# What is the name of this size method calculating the size of a node?

Tags: terminology, data-structures, trees, binary-trees, recursion

My confusion is that if the recursive call calls the left nodes, and then adds with the right nodes, how are the nodes that are to to right of the left nodes and vice versa being called?

```
int size (BinaryNode t) {
  if (t == null) 
    return 0;
  else
    return 1 + size(t.left) + size(t.right);   
}
```

Comment: `size` returns the number of nodes in `t`; proof by induction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that to get the actual value of `size(t.left)`, you have to evaluate the method `size` at the node `t.left`, i.e. assuming `t.left` has left and right children the algorithm with call `size((t.left).left)` and `size((t.left).right)`.